# discrete logistic dynamics problem

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Show that a solution to the discrete logistic dynamics $${{x}_{n+1}}=4{{x}_{n}}\left( 1-{{x}_{n}} \right)$$
can have the form of $${{x}_{n}}=A{{\sin }^{v}}{{b}^{n}}$$ Determine the $$A,\ v,\ b$$
Use the above result to illustrate chaos with a graph

Comment: You may find the identities $\sin^2u+\cos^2u=1$ and $\sin2u=2\sin u\cos u$ come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the function form, it should be clear that $v=2$, $b=2$, $A=1$.  Given how you'd worded your question, it is clear that you simply posted a homework problem, so I'll let you illustrate.

Comment: $n$ is a variable, not a constant. You meant $b$?

Comment: Yes, last time I do this on an iPad!